# element of array to string in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, streamreader, directoryinfo

I have this code written in Visual basic:

```
    Dim directory As String = Application.StartupPath()
    Dim dirinfo As New DirectoryInfo(directory)
    Dim filesnatt As String() = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.nat")
    Dim filenatt As String
    For Each filenatt In filesnatt
        Dim filenat As String = Str(filenatt)
        Using re As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filenat)
            Dim val As String = re.ReadLine()
            If val.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
                Dim a1 As String = filenat
                a1 = a1.Remove(".nat")
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(a1)
            End If
        End Using
    Next
```

But I get this error: Value of '1 - dimensional array of System.IO.FileInfo' cannot be converted to '1 - dimensional array of String' because 'System.IO.FileInfo' is not derived from 'String'.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

thats because `GetFiles` returns `FileInfo` instead of `String` change

```
Dim filesnatt as String() to Dim filesnatt as FileInfo()
```

and

```
Dim filenatt as String to Dim filenatt as FileInfo
```

and in the `For Each` loop use

```
Dim filenat as String = filenatt.FullName
```